# Google: How google search makes web site screenshot previews

Tags: graphics, screenshot, google-apps

Is there any ideas of how google search makes web site screenshot previews?

Sultan

Comment: Do you mean how they take the screenshots or how they show them when you are browsing through the search results?

Comment: @Harm De Weirdt yes definitely )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea how google does it but with [Awesomium](http://www.khrona.com/products/awesomium/) it's pretty easy.

Comment: This is commercial service. I was wondering if there any Open Source solution available?

Comment: @sultan, there's [khtml2png](http://thedailyubuntu.blogspot.com/2009/07/khtml2png-take-command-line-web.html).

Comment: so then how to avoid of using X server?

Comment: @sultan, this is tough, you will need a browser engine capable of interpreting the HTML and if it is a javascript intense site your engine will need to understand and execute javascript as well. That's why there are commercial solutions to this. It is not an easy task to achieve. Also `Awesomium` has a free license with display of logo.